# Trouble running spyder on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder

I installed spyder using "`sudo apt install spyder`" on my Ubuntu computer and the install appears to have gone fine, but when I try to open spyder (via clicking on the icon) it will not run. When I type "`spyder`" into the terminal I get the following message:

```
Update LANGUAGE_CODES (inside config/base.py) if a new translation has been added to Spyder
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('spyder==4.2.1', 'gui_scripts', 'spyder')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 213, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3624, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3482, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 803, in setup
    self.completions = CompletionManager(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/plugin.py", line 97, in __init__
    plugin_client = Plugin(self.main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/plugin.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.installer = KiteInstallerDialog(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 287, in __init__
    self._integration_widget = KiteIntegrationInfo(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 58, in __init__
    image = image.scaled(image_width, image_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  scaled(self, int, int, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  scaled(self, QSize, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Could anyone help me fix this?

I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling, rebooting. I'm not sure enough what the error messages mean to try and fix this myself.

Comment: Uninstall it `apt uninstall spyder`. Install it using pypi: `pip install spyder`. you may get an error `pip` does not exist. Try `pip3 install spyder`...